# Finding Extremes of Multivariable Function $f(x,y,z)=xz−yz $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am seeking assistance in finding the extrema of the function $f(x,y,z)=xz−yz$ when evaluated at points on the curve of intersection of two given surfaces. The surfaces of interest are defined by the following equations:

$$yz=2$$

$$ x^2+z^2=2$$

My goal is to determine the points at which the function $f$ reaches extrema (either maxima or minima) on the curve of intersection of these two surfaces. However, I need guidance on how to approach this problem.

So far, I have managed to parametrize the intersection curve and have concluded that the extrema of the function $f(x,y,z)$ on this curve correspond to points where the parameter of the parametrization, $t$, is constant. I have also derived the parametric equations for the curve:

$x(t) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2(t^2 - 2)}{t^2}}$

$y(t)=t$

$z(t) = \frac{2}{t}$

At this point, I find myself in need of determining the specific values of $t$ for which $f$ attains extrema on the curve. How can I proceed from here to ascertain whether these points are maxima or minima? Any further assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have this tagged under Lagrange multipliers, so how come you're parametrizing the intersection? Do you know how to deal with Lagrange multipliers with multiple constraints?

Comment: @OsamaGhani Thank you for your input. Initially, I chose to parametrize the intersection to simplify the problem before attempting to apply Lagrange multipliers. However, I'm facing some challenges with the Lagrange multipliers method. I opted for parametrization since the surfaces $yz=2$ and $x^2+z^2=2$ involve two variables, whereas the function $f$ has three variables

Comment: It might be worth trying the multiple constraints Lagrange multipliers. Because both functions are of just two variables, the system actually becomes really simple! But don't take my word for it. You get $(z, -z, x-y) = \lambda (0, z, y) + \mu (2x, 0, 2z)$ . This gives you $z = 2\mu x$, $-z = \lambda z$ and $x-y = \lambda y + 2\mu z$. We see a solution is that $\lambda = -1$, see if you can take it somewhere from here! Also don't forget to consider the cases where $\lambda = 0$ or $\mu = 0$.

Comment: If you really want to use your method, just write $f$ in terms of your parametrization and then you have a single variable function in terms of $t$ and find the derivative and set equal to $0$. Your sign ambiguity with the square root will lead this to be messy. You also need a domain for $t$ cause you have to test at the endpoints (unless perhaps your domain is all $t$, I didn't check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrange multiplier condition is that to find constrained extrema of $f$ subject to $g_1, g_2 = 0$, we solve the system $\nabla f = \lambda g_1 + \mu g_2$ (or some equivalent condition).

In this case, this reduces to $(z, -z, x-y) = \lambda (0, z, y) + \mu (2x, 0, 2z)$. For now, let's assume that both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are non-zero. Then we get

$$z = 2\mu x$$
$$-z = \lambda z$$
$$x-y = \lambda y + 2\mu z$$

From inspection, the second equation gives us $(\lambda +1)z = 0$. So let's try both cases (i.e. $z = 0$ or $\lambda = -1$)

If $\lambda = -1$, we get $z = 2\mu x$ and the bottom equation becomes $x = 2\mu z$. Add em up and we have $x+z = 2\mu (x+z)$. Rearranging, we have $(2\mu-1)(x+z) = 0$. So either $\mu = \frac{1}{2}$ or $x = -z$. Let's try both. With $\mu = 1/2$, we have $z = x$. Great so essentially we have $x = \pm z$, sub this into $g_2$ and we get $2x^2 = 2$ or $x = \pm 1$. Following carefully, this gives us the following points to test at $(1,2,1), (1,-2,-1), (-1,-2,-1), (-1,2,1)$.

I'm not going to complete the answer to the question but you need to go back and consider what if $z = 0$, and what if $\lambda = 0$ and what if $\mu = 0$ (why?). Spoiler alert though, our maxima and minima are actually all at those $4$ points we just found above!

Comment: Thank you very much! I notice that if λ = 0 and μ = 0, there seems to be no issue. However, if z = 0, I encounter a problem in the equation yz - 2 = 0, which results in 0 = 2, which is absurd. So, I understand that (0,0,0) is not a solution point of the system of equations. Is that correct?

Comment: You're right that $z=0$ leads to something nonsensical. With $\mu = 0$ note that the first equation implies $z = 0$ so we're back to it not working, and with $\lambda = 0$, the second equation implies $z = 0$ so we're back to it not working, so we did indeed find all our points to test at above!

Comment: Thank you very much! A question, I know that if I have a continuous function on a closed and bounded constraint (region), then the function will attain an absolute maximum and an absolute minimum value within the constraint. My question is: I understand that the function in this exercise is continuous because it's a polynomial function. However, are both constraints closed and bounded? I believe they are not. So, in the case that they are not, would my critical points (1,2,1), (1,-2,-1), (-1,-2,-1), (-1,2,1) be local extremes and not absolute ones?

Comment: Also now that I think about it, it may not have been necessary to assume $\lambda$ or $\mu$ are non-zero since we didn't divide by them anywhere, so just the above work should suffice!

Comment: When you have constrained optimization, there isn't really a good notion of local extrema. You're right that a continuous function on a compact (closed and bounded) domain achieves extrema. However, Lagrange multipliers will find absolute extrema satisfying constraints *if they exist*. You're totally right that they need not have existed, and you can come up with problems where they will not exist. But if they do, you can find them using this method

Comment: I see, thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

No Lagrange multipliers are needed.
We have $$f(x,y,z)=xz-yz=xz-2$$ Moreover $$-1=-{1\over 2}(x^2+z^2)\le xz\le{1\over 2}(x^2+z^2)=1$$ The first equality holds iff $x=-z=\pm 1,$ while the second iff $x=z=\pm 1.$ Therefore the maximal value is equal $-1$ and the minimal value is equal $-3.$ By analyzing the above the maximal value is attained at two points $\,\pm (1,2,1)$ and the minimal value at two points $\,\pm (-1,2,1).$
The methods shows that the values $-1$ and $-3$ are global extremes.